# React dropdown selected value is not filtered after refresh page

Tags: reactjs, dropdown

i have some problems, i am using devextreme(Tagbox) dropdown, i have a list of my grid and filtered very well. but when i am refreshing the page filter is gone(the grid behavior seems like selectall from to my db) i am research on stack overflow this issue, some people says use localstorage, and i did it, but couldn't find any solutions i don't know whats the best way doing that,

i did selected target value and then pass to data my state, after that i don't know what will i do right now.. Thank you!
this my code;

```
 <TagBox
          dataSource={this.getRegions}
          displayExpr="name"
          valueExpr="id"
          onValueChanged={this.onRegionChanged}
        />

         onRegionChanged = (e) => {
          LS._setItem("FilterRegion", e.value);
         const FilteredRegion = LS._getItem("FilterRegion");
         this.setState((prevState) => ({
          ...prevState.FilteredRegion,
         FilterRegion: FilteredRegion,
         }));
         console.log(this.state.FilterRegion);
```